# @angular/bazel not working in new angular 9 project

Tags: angular, bazel, angular9

I was really excited with latest version of Angular 9!! and thought of giving try to Ivy and Bazel.But stuck on very early step. My project is not even getting started :( . I have used below latest technologies .

```
Angular CLI: 9.0.3
Node: 12.3.1
OS: win32 x64
windows 10

Angular: 9.0.2
... animations, bazel, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core
... forms, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router
Ivy Workspace: Yes

Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.900.3
@angular-devkit/core         9.0.3
@angular-devkit/schematics   9.0.3
@angular/cli                 9.0.3
@bazel/bazel                 2.1.0
@bazel/hide-bazel-files      1.3.0
@bazel/ibazel                0.11.1
@bazel/karma                 1.3.0
@bazel/protractor            1.3.0
@bazel/rollup                1.3.0
@bazel/terser                1.3.0
@bazel/typescript            1.3.0
@schematics/angular          9.0.3
@schematics/update           0.900.3
rxjs                         6.5.4
typescript                   3.7.5
```

Now when i run "ng serve" getting below error

```
E:\..\bazeltest>ng serve
iBazel [11:17AM]: Error getting Bazel info exit status 2
iBazel [11:17AM]: Querying for files to watch...
)) was unexpected at this time.
iBazel [11:17AM]: Bazel query failed: exit status 255
Loading: 0 packages loaded
ERROR: ../external/build_bazel_rules_nodejs/internal/npm_install/npm_install.bzl:308:13: Traceback (most recent call last):
        File ".../6t4oby46/external/build_bazel_rules_nodejs/internal/npm_install/npm_install.bzl", line 307
                repository_rule(attrs = dict(COMMON_ATTRIBUTES, ...)}), <2 more arguments>)
        File "...../6t4oby46/external/build_bazel_rules_nodejs/internal/npm_install/npm_install.bzl", line 308, in repository_rule
                dict(COMMON_ATTRIBUTES, **{"args": attr...)})
got multiple values for keyword argument 'args', for call to function dict(args = [], **kwargs)
ERROR: ..../6t4oby46/external/build_bazel_rules_nodejs/internal/npm_install/npm_install.bzl:432:13: Traceback (most recent call last):
        File ".../6t4oby46/external/build_bazel_rules_nodejs/internal/npm_install/npm_install.bzl", line 431
                repository_rule(attrs = dict(COMMON_ATTRIBUTES, ...)}), <2 more arguments>)
        File ".../6t4oby46/external/build_bazel_rules_nodejs/internal/npm_install/npm_install.bzl", line 432, in repository_rule
                dict(COMMON_ATTRIBUTES, **{"args": attr...)})
got multiple values for keyword argument 'args', for call to function dict(args = [], **kwargs)
ERROR: error loading package '': in .../6t4oby46/external/build_bazel_rules_nodejs/index.bzl: Extension file 'internal/npm_install/npm_inst
all.bzl' has errors
Loading: 0 packages loaded
Loading: 0 packages loaded
iBazel [11:17AM]: Bazel query failed: exit status 7
iBazel [11:17AM]: Running //src:devserver
Loading: 0 packages loaded
ERROR: ..../6t4oby46/external/build_bazel_rules_nodejs/internal/npm_install/npm_install.bzl:308:13: Traceback (most recent call last):
        File ".../6t4oby46/external/build_bazel_rules_nodejs/internal/npm_install/npm_install.bzl", line 307
                repository_rule(attrs = dict(COMMON_ATTRIBUTES, ...)}), <2 more arguments>)
        File "..../6t4oby46/external/build_bazel_rules_nodejs/internal/npm_install/npm_install.bzl", line 308, in repository_rule
                dict(COMMON_ATTRIBUTES, **{"args": attr...)})
got multiple values for keyword argument 'args', for call to function dict(args = [], **kwargs)
ERROR: .../6t4oby46/external/build_bazel_rules_nodejs/internal/npm_install/npm_install.bzl:432:13: Traceback (most recent call last):
        File
 ".../6t4oby46/external/build_bazel_rules_nodejs/internal/npm_install/npm_install.bzl", line 431
                repository_rule(attrs = dict(COMMON_ATTRIBUTES, ...)}), <2 more arguments>)
        File 
".......y46/external/build_bazel_rules_nodejs/internal/npm_install/npm_install.bzl", line 432, in repository_rule
                dict(COMMON_ATTRIBUTES, **{"args": attr...)})
got multiple values for keyword argument 'args', for call to function dict(args = [], **kwargs)
ERROR: error loading package '': in ...../6t4oby46/external/build_bazel_rules_nodejs/index.bzl: Extension file 'internal/npm_install/npm_inst
all.bzl' has errors

Loading: 0 packages loaded
Loading: 0 packages loaded
iBazel [11:17AM]: Error running Bazel exit status 7
...\bazeltest\node_modules\@bazel\ibazel\bin\windows_amd64\ibazel.exe failed with code 4.
```

I am not sure  whats wrong is going on. I followed angular official page.

https://angular.io/guide/bazel

Comment: same issue on win10, `'ngcc' is not recognized as an internal or external command`

Comment: Tracked as https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/35740